# Comunicação Arduino e PHP via serial

Tags: php, arduino, serial

Amigos, me perdoem pelo post, mas não entendo de PHP.
Eu já até li alguns outros posts aqui no site, apliquei algumas coisas mas virou uma bagunça.
A ideia é fazer o PHP enviar uma letra que servirá como gatilho para o arduino retornar um valor (no meu caso a temperatura de um termômetro) via porta serial (COMx)
O arduino está retornando certo a temperatura no prompt interno dele, a dificuldade somente é exportar esses dados parar a página PHP.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<?php
include 'PhpSerial.php';

$serial = new PhpSerial;


$serial->deviceSet("COM7");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");


$serial->deviceOpen();

sleep (2);





var_dump (fgets ($serial));
if (!$serial)
{
    echo "Não foi possível abrir a porta serial";
}
else
{
    echo "Conectado a porta serial com sucesso";
}
sleep(1);
$serial->sendMessage("t");
sleep (1);
echo fgets ($serial);
sleep (2);
fclose($serial);
?>
```

Comment: Eu não conheço muito de arduino, mas suponho que tenha que disponibilizar estes dados escrevendo o script dentro do Arduino escrito em `C`.

Comment: Eu também achava isso. Mas vi uns exemplos que o pessoal só pede pro PHP ler a porta serial e imprimir na tela os resultados.O arduino só envia o resultado da leitura dos sensores.
Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme